# Power Series converging to Function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

To what function does this Power Series converges to
$P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=\infty}(j+1)(j+2)x^j$

I know its nothing but $P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=\infty}\frac{(j+2)!}{j!}x^j$

So what is the function it converges to and How?

Comment: Compute $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\sum_{j\geq 0}x^{j+2}$ a recall the geometric serie

Comment: But what does $\sum_{j\geq 0}x^{j+2}$ converge to? I don't recall a proper function

Comment: Hey, I  think I got it $\sum_{ j\geq 0}x^{j+2}$ converges to $$\frac{x^2}{1-x}$$ Hence double integral of it will give the solution. Correct?

Comment: Double derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is know that $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then, we have in one hand
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n+2}=\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left (x^2\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n}\right )=\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left ( x^2\frac{1}{1-x}\right )$$
and in the other hand
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n+2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}x^{n+2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}
$$